# I got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I tried to read a file with spark.read

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory

I have a one-line json file with 100Mb that I'm trying to read, but when I try to do it on the jupyter, it gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
The code I'm using is the code below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("test - python") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json("file.json")

df.show()
spark.close
```

Throws:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:68)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:106)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffer.java:455)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:336)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:146)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:134)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:168)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:183)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:134)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:168)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:134)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.inferField(JsonInferSchema.scala:168)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$4(JsonInferSchema.scala:88)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$Lambda$2982/2109809202.apply(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2764)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$2(JsonInferSchema.scala:86)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$Lambda$2943/1560107660.apply(Unknown Source)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
   at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:387)
   at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty$(Iterator.scala:387)
   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1431)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:249)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:248)
   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$1(JsonInferSchema.scala:103)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$Lambda$2924/1533266266.apply(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably, you are running out of memory. How much memory did you expect this to require? How much memory do you have available?

Comment: I'm using a ec2 instance with 16gb, but to my knowledge the spark shouldn't consume that much memory just to read an file.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: because it's a 100Mb file versus a 16Gb memory and the spark should only load the file after an action, and the only thing that I'm doing to the data is show the top 20. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: How much memory do you expect the JSON data to take once it is *deserialized*? You understand, it won't be the same as it takes when it is serialized? Consider, in Python, the json: `{"foo": "bar"}`. On disk, that takes about 14 bytes. In memory, as a `dict` object, this requires about 336 bytes

Comment: Now, I don't know how spark handles JSON. It may have to read the whole thing into memory first. JSON typically is not a very good format for streaming